# Converting string array to list of strings

Tags: f#

Is there an easy way to convert a string array into a list of strings in F#? I'm rather new to F# and I can't find anything on this while searching.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Array.toList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353606.aspx):

```
let myArray = [| "foo"; "bar"; "baz" |] 
let myList = myArray |> Array.toList
```

Or for that matter, [`Seq.toList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353889.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

A universal way is with library function from source collection type module [`Array.toList : 'T [] -> 'T list`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353606.aspx). It works for **any** type of elements `'T`.

In particular, for `'T` being `string`:

```
[| "S1"; "S2"; "S3" |] |> Array.toList
```

Or similarly universally, but with library function from target collection type module[`List.ofArray : 'T [] -> 'T list`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370614.aspx):

```
[| "S1"; "S2"; "S3" |] |> List.ofArray
```